# Dart Pointer elementAt Depreciated. How do I change my code to use + operator?

Tags: dart

The below line `ptr.elementAt(i).value = list[i];` causes this warning

'elementAt' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use operator + instead.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.

vscode does not offer a correction.

The documentation does not explain the new required syntax.

Can someone please show me how to change the the code correctly?  Thank you!

```
Pointer<Double> doubleListToPointer(List<double> list) {
  final ptr = malloc.allocate<Double>(sizeOf<Double>() * list.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    ptr.elementAt(i).value = list[i];
  }

  return ptr;
}
```

Tried to use vscode intellisense to offer a correction but it couldn't provide one.

I checked the Pointer docs but explanation was provided to transition the code from elementAt to the `+` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case you don't even have to use the `+` or `-` operator. In your code, the only correction is to not use the `elementAt` method.

Instead you can simply use the `[]` operator to access and `=` operator to set the value. Here's the corrected code:

```
Pointer<Double> doubleListToPointer(List<double> list) {
  final ptr = malloc.allocate<Double>(sizeOf<Double>() * list.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    ptr[i] = list[i];
  }

  return ptr;
}
```

Hope this helps!